# Sum of range---getting "undefined"

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, for-loop, range

I'm looking for the sum of a range but I keep getting "undefined." I believe something's in the wrong spot but I'm not sure as to what it is.

Part 1: "Write a range function that takes two arguments, start and end, and returns an array containing all of the numbers from start up to (and including) end:

Part 2: "Next, write a sum function that takes an array of numbers and returns the sum of these numbers. Run the previous program and see whether it does indeed return 55."

```js
// Part 1
function deRange(start, end, step) {

  if (step === null) {
    step = 1;

    var blank = [];

    if (step > 0) {
      for (var i = start; i <= end; i += step)
        blank.push(i);
    } else {
      for (var i = start; i >= end; i += step)
        blank.push(i);
    }
  }
  return blank;
}

// Part 2
function theSum(blank) {
  var total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < blank.length; i++)
    total += blank[i];
  return total;
}

console.log(deRange(1, 10));
console.log(deRange(5, 2, -1));
console.log(theSum(deRange(1, 10)));
```

Comment: Is it because of the `}` bracket after the second `for` loop, maybe?

Comment: You're missing the 3rd argument in `deRange`. Even if it's null, you should explicitly call it (`deRange(1, 2, null)`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below I fixed your code and commented some errors you have in it. Check the demo.

```js
// Part 1
function deRange(start, end, step) {

  /**
   * If you want to make sure 'step' is not 0 (zero) either,
   * change the if like this:
   * if(!step) { step = 1; }
   */
  if (step === null || typeof step === 'undefined') { // <- also check when 'step' was not passed as argument
    step = 1;
  } // <-- curly brace here!
  var blank = [];

  if (step > 0) {
    for (var i = start; i <= end; i += step)
      blank.push(i);
  } else {
    for (var i = start; i >= end; i += step)
      blank.push(i);
  }
  return blank;
}

// Part 2
function theSum(blank) {
  var total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < blank.length; i++)
    total += blank[i];
  return total;
}

console.log(deRange(1, 10));
console.log(deRange(5, 2, -1));
console.log(theSum(deRange(1, 10)));
```

Comment: thanks! I didn't realize that both "undefined" and "null" had to be in the first if statement.

Comment: I'm glad to help, @Tsardines. Notice I updated my answer in order to give you an additional "tip". In case the user provides `0` as `step` the function will get inside an infinite loop. So if you want to make sure `step` is never `0` when it reaches the `loop` replace your `if` for this one: `if(!step) { step = 1; }`

Answer (score 1):

You have misplaced your curly brackets. This works:

```js
function range(start, end, step) {
  if (step === null) {
    step = 1;
  }
  var blank = [];
  if (step > 0) {
    for (var i = start; i <= end; i += step)
      blank.push(i);
  } else {
    for (var i = start; i >= end; i += step)
      blank.push(i);
  }
  return blank;
}
console.log(range(1, 5, null));
```

Note that you are checking if `step` is `null`, so the user still needs to explicitly give `null` as argument. If you want to set a default value if no third argument is provided, use e.g.:

```
step = step || 1;
```

(This also treats `0` as a missing argument, which is good.)